# Convert colums to rows in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have this table of data. Each row represents 6 months of data (Quantity).

EX: Year = 2016 and Term = 1 means Mon1 to Mon6 is Jan to June

If Term = 2 Means July to December.

[image]

Above data I have to show as below. Need 3 columns of data like

[image]

So each product must be 12 months data from current month.

Means, Current month June then 2016June to 2017May (Including current month)

Can you please suggest with some script to retrieve this data from above table?

Comment: Is the ProductId & Item Id are same!?

Comment: Please explain more about your expected output. Try to add input and output that are related. provided sample data is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try this, the part to get month number is tricky, I have used the column names, you need to change that part if column names are not the same i.e. mon1, mon2 and so on.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (ProductID INT, [Year] INT, Team INT, Mon1 INT, Mon2 INT, Mon3 INT, Mon4 INT, Mon5 INT, Mon6 INT)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
VALUES   (1, 2016, 1, 10,20,30,40,50,60) 
        ,(1, 2016, 2, 10,20,30,40,50,60)        
        ,(1, 2017, 1, 10,20,30,40,50,60)
        ,(1, 2017, 2, 10,20,30,40,50,60)
        ,(2, 2016, 1, 10,20,30,40,50,60) 
        ,(2, 2016, 2, 10,20,30,40,50,60)        
        ,(2, 2017, 1, 10,20,30,40,50,60)
        ,(2, 2017, 2, 10,20,30,40,50,60)
        ,(3, 2016, 1, 10,20,30,40,50,60) 
        ,(3, 2016, 2, 10,20,30,40,50,60)        
        ,(3, 2017, 1, 10,20,30,40,50,60)
        ,(3, 2017, 2, 10,20,30,40,50,60)
        ,(4, 2016, 1, 10,20,30,40,50,60) 
        ,(4, 2016, 2, 10,20,30,40,50,60)        
        ,(4, 2017, 1, 10,20,30,40,50,60)
        ,(4, 2017, 2, 10,20,30,40,50,60)

DECLARE @FromYear INT, @FromYearMonth INT, @ToYear INT, @ToYearMonth INT

-- Get from - to yearmonth base on current date.
SELECT  @FromYear = YEAR(GETDATE()), 
        @ToYear = YEAR( DATEADD(month,11,GETDATE()))  -- add 11 months as it starts from current month

SELECT  @FromYearMonth = @FromYear * 100 + MONTH(GETDATE()), 
        @ToYearMonth = @ToYear * 100 + MONTH( DATEADD(month,11,GETDATE())) 

SELECT  @FromYear, @ToYear, @FromYearMonth, @ToYearMonth  -- check the dates.

;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ProductID, 
        [Year], 
        Team, 
        Quantity, 
        CASE WHEN Team = 2 THEN RIGHT(Months,1) + 6 ELSE RIGHT(Months,1) END Mon, -- get month number
        ([Year] * 100) + CASE WHEN Team = 2 THEN RIGHT(Months,1) + 6 ELSE RIGHT(Months,1) END YearMonth -- get YearMonth value
    FROM (  SELECT *
            FROM @MyTable
            WHERE [YEAR] BETWEEN @FromYear AND @ToYear -- filter data for year range
    ) x
    UNPIVOT
    ( Quantity FOR Months IN (Mon1,Mon2,Mon3,Mon4,Mon5,Mon6)        -- deflat row-cols
    ) p
) 
SELECT ProductID, YearMonth, Quantity, Team, Mon
FROM CTE 
WHERE YearMonth BETWEEN @FromYearMonth AND @ToYearMonth -- filer final data.
```